# CentOS Postfix/Dovecot status deferred conversation with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp, dovecot, stunnel

- Linux Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.i686 on i686
- RAM: 6GB
- OS: CentOS 6.6
- Postfix 2.6.6
- Dovecot 2.0.9
- Relay Host Verizon
- Stunnel through 127.0.0.1:2525
- Webmin 1.750
- Virtualmin 4.17.gpl
- Multiple Domains
- IMAP only no POP3

So here is the issue: I have been trying to setup my Postfix/Dovecot and at one time I had email going out (pre-Dovecot) and then I installed Dovecot and email stopped working (but I can connect to Dovecot through email app). I have searched all over the internet and followed many different How-To's.

So here is the error log message:

```
May 27 12:53:17 HOST dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=USERACCOUNT, method=PLAIN, rip=EXTERNALIP, lip=INTERNALIP, mpid=24257, TLS

May 27 12:56:18 HOST postfix/smtp[24155]: 34AF0120A1C: to=RECEPIENTEMAIL, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:2525, delay=41158, delays=40858/0.06/300/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (conversation with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

- I have replaced the host name with HOST, the external ip with EXTERNALIP, the internal IP with INTERNALIP, and the recepient email with RECEPIENTEMAIL

Here is the output of my postconf -n

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:2525
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, loginsender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_password_map
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases_map
```

I'm at wits end! Someone please help me!

Ideal scenario: I want to run my postfix server to serve mail to my domain users. All email will be routed to smtp.verizon.net through port 465. In coming mail would be delivered directly to my postfix server. Users will be able to use Outlook or other email clients to connect to the server and read/send mail. I will also be installing Roundcube or SquirrelMail to have a webmail for them to use. All email and login should go through SSL/TLS (using self-signed certs - no commercial certs yet though this may change at a later time).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: - Connection: FIOS Business with Dynamic IP (so I still have port 25 blocked)

Comment: Yes it is Stunnel I configured stunnel to listen on 127.0.0.1:2525
when telnet to 127.0.0.1:2525 I get

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

My STUNNEL Config
fips = no
client = no

[smtp-tls-wrapper]
accept = 2525
connect = smtp.verizon.net:465

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question. Where the other end of stunnel? Smtp.verizon.net? And please try to do SMTP transaction on it

Comment: sorry, I hit enter and it posted the answer (I have edited my comment)

Comment: Keep in mind that prior to me installing Dovecot, the server was sending out email. It was through the process of installing and configuring Dovecot that Postfix broke. So I agree, the connection to the Postfix/Stunnel is broken, but how do I fix it? I will leave the question open in hopes that I get some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to **fix** it as I still can't pinpoint which broken part in your case. However, I can give you tips to **troubleshoot** it. Set debug on stunnel into level  7 and look at it. Perhaps you will find it some errors